# Security error. What to do

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, tinymce, file-manager

I have a problem with responsive file manager for tinymce, files easy upload and download. But when i try to add my file in edit space of my editor i have an error. Didnt know what to do with it.

That error i recive in ChromeBrowser

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://actamedical.loc"
from accessing a frame with origin "http://actamedical.loc". The frame being
accessed set "document.domain" to "actamedical.loc", but the frame requesting
access did not. Both must set "document.domain" to the same value to allow access.
```

That in firefox.

```
Error: Permission denied to access property 'accessKey'
Error: Permission denied to access property 'tinymce'

...("href")+"&"+new Date().getTime()},500)})}})}}}],{header:$("#lang_new_file").val...
```

Maby someone knows where is a problem. Thanks.